# Entitiy Framework 6.0.2 Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Using a DB first implementation for a small series of projects in a solution. So far so good, but now I have a need to do some bulk importing from time to time.

[Viewing a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework?lq=1) it references AutoDetectChanges, which I don't see in this version of EF (6.0.2).

I've run myself in a circle now and I'm certain I'm missing the tree for the forest so any direction would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps provide some code to accompany your question?